# How to handle deleting forms shown modally on Macs where have TPopups?

Tags: delphi, c++builder

Using FMX in C++ Builder 10.1 with update, it seems that doing the following can cause a problem on Macs. (I am using macOS Sierra, but it seems the problem occurred in previous OS versions as well.)

1. Create form using new operator.
2. Show form modally.
3. Form sets modal result > 0.
4. delete form from calling form.

where the close image on the modally displayed form has a TPopup with contextual help, where the TPopup's IsOpen value is set to false on a MouseLeave event.

It seems what is happening is that, sometimes, the form is being deleted before the TPopup code is processed because the mouse is no longer over the image. This causes an error and, on Macs, simply closes the program. The bug is fixed by removing the OnMouseLeave event from the button.

I do not have this problem when the target OS is Windows.

My first question is whether this is a bug (the image's OnMouseLeave event handler setting the TPopup's IsOpen=false should be processed properly when the form is closed), and my second is what approach should be used to handle this sort of problem?

Comment: Please provide a MCVE

Comment: If by 'delete' you literally mean the C++ keyword, use the Release method instead.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - as I said, you don't, you call the Release method instead. Given the topic is when to 'delete' the form, this isn't even FMX specific.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - erm, you are familiar with Release in a VCL context, right...? FMX has the same, in fact it's generalised (the method is declared on TFmxObject, a base class above TControl and TCustomForm).

Comment: @chris er, yes, was getting confused, sorry

Comment: @ChrisRolliston

Comment: Release fixes the problem. Thank you.